# Order file by colum where column is a date

Tags: bash, sorting, date, column

I have a file in the following format

```
222 aaaaa 2021-12-24
333fd bbb 2021-09-1
444 cc 2022-01-16
555 zzz 2021-08-21
6666 www 2021-09-5
777 yyy 2021-03-14
888 xxx 2021-11-27
999 ffffff 2021-12-4
```

I am trying to order the file based on the date column.

I have tried to sort :

- with option `-t "-" -k2` delimiter but doesn't work. (tried to order by month at least)
- with option `-k3.4` (it can order by the 4th char of the year 2021/2022), piping with `| sort -n -k3.5` but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YYYY-MM-DD can be sorted alphabetically, so the only thing you need is to add the leading zeroes to days.

```
sed -E 's/-(.)$/-0\1/' file | sort -k3
```

You can add `| sed -E 's/-0(.)$/-\1/'` to get back the original format (but why?).

Comment: thanks! the -n also was sorting it wrongly

Comment: @xavi: That's because `-t "-"` prepends the first two columns to year.